# SQL query to find values depending on other values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an application for text management. There are many short texts in different languages, which need to fit in text areas with given width (px) and number of lines. The goal is to find all texts which does not use the available linewidth to a certain exceed, to show them to the user for editing.
Example:
[image]
On the left text each line does only take a quarter of the available space, which is bad. The text on the right is ok.

I have this table lengthcheckresult which would look like this for the left example

```
id, idText, lineorder, usedspace, availablespace
3   87      1          111        430
4   87      2          116        430
5   87      3          171        430
6   87      4          120        430
```

and like this for the right example:

```
id, idText, lineorder, usedspace, availablespace
3   87      1          408        430
4   87      2          120        430
5   87      3            0        430
6   87      4            0        430
```

So I need an SQL query which finds all texts with lines which take less than x  percent of the available space when followed by more lines. Do you think this is possible? I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this (making assumptions about table names etc.)

```
select
  A.id
--, (anything else you want)
from dbname.dbo.tblname A
where usedspace > 0
  and availablespace > 0 -- Avoid divide by zero
  and usedspace / availablespace < 0.5  -- Assume less than 50%? Pick your value.
  and A.idText = 1234 -- The text of interest
  and exists
  ( select B.id from dbname.dbo.tblname B
    where B.idText = A.idText        -- Part of same text
      and B.lineorder > A.lineorder  -- Only later lines
      and B.usedspace > 0            -- Only non-empty lines
  )
-- order by etc, as required.
```

This finds you pieces of text that are shorter than an arbitrary percentage (in this case 50%) which also have following text that is not empty.